# Do we count the identity element as an element of a finite group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

When talking about the order of a finite group, do we take the identity element into account?

Here is a theorem I read from the book 'Algebra and Geometry' by Alan. F.Beardon:

> Let $G$ be a finite group in which every element has order two. Then $G$ is abelian, and has order $2^m$ for some integer $m$.

It does not make sense if I include the identity element $e$, as it clearly has order 1, yet the theorem states 'every element has order two'.

Could someone clarify this please?

Comment: You are right, one should read either "every element has order dividing two" or "every non-trivial element has order two". And to answer the first question, the identity is an element of the group.

Comment: I think this is what people call "abuse of notation".

Comment: My guess is Beardon was thinking, every element $x$ satisfies $x^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Correct.

Every group  contains an identity. In fact, the most common of axiomatisation of groups has the existence of an identity as an axiom.

---

The text should be this:

> Let $G$ be a finite group in which every nontrivial element has order two. Then $G$ is abelian, and has order $2^m$ for some integer $m$.